# Reporting a serial downvoting against all my questions and answers to keep my votes under 125!

Tags: discussion

If you claim this is a fair site and there are equal reaction toward different users by mods and no matter they are Iranians or Americans and their lovers and followers, please prove it by doing your bests to teach people it is not a good way to take a revenge by taking the right of freedom of speech of a special user only because she is the one who has a voice here for her points of view as an Iranian in politics.

I do not know it is by one user or more than one but serial downvoting is serial downvoting and it is not different it is by one or more like serial grouping attacks!

If I am one here it doesn't mean this site can ignore all my rights according to the will of a group of people who have similar ideas against my ideas and give a right to themselves to impose their ideas to me and if I do not accept they kill me by unfair downvotes! It is disgusting! but surely if I am wrong about good will of mods of SE and Politics site it will be useless to make a question here about it.

It was a suggestion by one of mods of this site to make a question about it here so if there are downvotes again for this question and surely it doesn't mean I am asking all users if they agree with showing a reaction by mods against serial downvoters or not! The serial downvoter or downvoters can downvote this question too so their ideas should not change the FAQ and rules of this site to protect their own ideas and wrong reactions against me.

I hope mods prove they are managing here according to the FAQ not according to a special propaganda or some prejudice users. If not no problem! Only please do not claim something else and be honest! I will keep silence and will not take you serious more than it and will leave you continue to your sweet dreaming but surely there are many eyes which are following you here and it can show an ugly image of you and your claims in international cyber networks.

.........

P.S: I am sorry to have to explain very obvious matters but anyway... When you receive downvotes for all your old and new questions and answers at the second while they have had upvotes before it it shows a clear grouping attack or an attempt by one user because of anger about that famous question and answer which all you know about which made mad Prejudice Americans. All my questions have high quality as they had upvotes before I make that sensitive question! I am sorry to say there is a clear protection by one of mods Yannis of downvoters and he repeatly insults me by his strong irrelavant comments in different questions. He deletes all my comments which are replies to irrelevant comments or are answers to some questions in comments. He judges my comments after deleting them and repeats his wrong judgements again and after answering him as my right to defend of myself against an ugly attempt by him, he deleted my comments and sends strong warnings! It is ugly! I have to talk about it here because It is not fair a mod out of etiquette and respect tries an ugly way in mocking one user and abuse of his power against her according to his personal ideas. It is shameful and a real awkward reaction. I hope see some changes here in moderating system or a rule to stop mods who misuse their powers.

Anyway it was all the matter! You can hear and try to improve your system or ignore it! I doesn't matter for me anymore. I am disappointed about it.

.............

About low quality questions:

There are all my questions with their votes:

2  Did the USA ever officially apologize for shooting down “Iran Air Flight 655” in July of 1988?

2   When was the last face to face meeting between Iran government and USA government?

1   What are the political consequences of an official apology for a governement?

0   Is it allowed in the united states to advertise for a peaceful political meeting in social networks against the government?

If they were low quality they didn't have upvotes, many followers and surely answers and you had deleted them or closed them without asking me! So what do you mean of low quality?! Please talk according to evidences,facts and examples not according to your imagination or desires!

And this is the serial downvoting against all questions at a second after sending an answer to my own last question which bothered prejudice Americans and their lovers and caused provocative comments and my replies to them which all have been deleted unless Yaniss's warnings and his strong words against only me and his obvious attempts to protect of angry comments and turns it to something else:

-1   today

-1   28 mins ago    downvoted   Did the USA ever officially apologize for shooting down “Iran Air Flight 655” in 3 July of 1988?

-2   yesterday

+10      18:45  2 events     Did the USA ever officially apologize for shooting down “Iran Air Flight 655” in 3 July of 1988?

-2   15:26  downvote    Did the USA ever officially apologize for shooting down “Iran Air Flight 655” in 3 July of 1988?

-2   12:38  downvote    Is it allowed in the united states to advertise for a peaceful political meeting in social networks against the government?

-2   12:37  downvote    What are the political consequences of an official apology for a governement?

-2   12:37  downvote    When was the last face to face meeting between Iran government and USA government?

-4   12:50  2 events     Did the USA ever officially apologize for shooting down “Iran Air Flight 655” in 3 July of 1988?

-5   2 days ago

-1   16:19  downvoted   How dangerous a threat does North Korea pose to the world?

-4  22:49   3 events     Did the USA ever officially apologize for shooting down “Iran Air Flight 655” in 3 July of 1988?

-2    Apr 2

-2    Mar 26

So if all this is not clear for you I can't help more. Nothing can help you more!

.....................

P.S: The serial downvoting has been recognized by the system and reversed yesterday but again there are some signs of another serial downvoting. I hope in this time mods try to find The abuser who is gaming the system to take a personal revenge of me and suspend him for some days.

It is interesting to know I have been suspended many times for exactly nothing and only for trying to correct bold discrimination and offensive language of some users and mods of different sites against myself as an Iranian feminist but when I am complaining about clear and obvious personal attacks against myself there is no suspension for abusers! So what does it mean? How can I ignore it and do not take it personal? Surely I take personal, personal attacks and obvious wrong attempts by racists,anti feminists and propaganda followers about myself. To get it better I guide you to leave your strong prejudice which causes defending of this ugly reactions and accept your faults in EL&U site,ELL site,History site and Politics site against me. There are facts,examples, archives and evidences which by following my questions and answers and the reactions of mods of these sites against them you can get it easily if you really want. It seems being an Iranian is not equal to being an Italian, American or anything else to have same punishments about our same (Not even same but I ignore myself and consider we all had same faults!) faults. It is a sample of reality in the real world to find how racism and anti feminism ideas can hide themselves in public places but unfortunately it is not possible in cyber spaces even if you try to close your eyes against it.

I hope an open mind and an honest heart for all users of SE!

-4    yesterday

-2    14:46     downvote    Did the USA ever officially apologize for shooting down  “Iran Air Flight 655” in 3 July of 1988?

-2    14:46     downvote    Did the USA ever officially apologize for shooting down “Iran Air Flight 655” in 3 July of 1988?

-2    2 days ago

-2    02:09     downvote    What are the political consequences of an official apology for a governement?

11    Apr 6

+10       17:20     reversal    Serial downvoting reversed

+1    17:20     undownvoted     Does non-religious opposition to feminism exist? If so, why?

Comment: There's an automated script that looks at suspicious voting patterns.  It will run at the end of the day. If your reputation hasn't been update, then I'd flag one of your posts for moderator attention and then they can have it looked into.  However, you might want to consider that multiple people are voting on the quality of your content, and nothing else.  We give people the benefit of the doubt here.

Comment: Sometimes what looks like a "serial" downvote is actually a number of people downvoting because of the quality of contributions.

Comment: @casperOne I do not know how it works but if it is according to definite numbers of question and answers it may do not work for me because I do not have many questions and answers!

Comment: It looks like you posted this answer http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/did-the-usa-ever-officially-apologize-for-shooting-down-iran-air-flight-655-in not long ago

Comment: @PersianCat I've told you _twice_ in comments that you have to wait 24 hours for the script to run and you acknowledged that you read and understood my comments.

Comment: ...and since then have gathered a lot of downvotes.  That's kind of how votes work.  "Freedom of speech" means you can say what you want but I can also tell you that it's terrible and I disagree - part of that on the SE network is downvoting.

Comment: @JNK It can't be according to your hypothesis OBVIOUSLY when you see all your questions are taking downvotes after making one answer which is bothering dear prejudice American users of this site. What kind of fair can be when one or some users try it in one second against all questions of one user and make neutral all previous upvotes? It is very easy to find! Which kind of quality is which is changing according to taste of some during only one month! This logic cannot even convince a 5 years old kid! It reminds me their reactions toward that question and answer. :)

Comment: @JNK It is not about that special question but about my old questions here! Right? So please do not use of comment to protect downvoters. Please listen to Yaniss advices and stop it here.

Comment: Well sometimes what happens in those scenarios is posting a particular question or answer gets you unwanted attention on other posts you have made.  We see this a lot when people complain on Meta.SO about question being closed - their account gets more visibility and people downvote their posts.

Comment: @YannisRizos Surely NO when it happens at a second about all questions old and new at the same moment. Anyway I am tired of explaning very easy and obvious thing here. you are trying to stop me in comments ans then you ask me something in protecting of downvoters with a wrong logic.

Comment: Perhaps another part of the issue is a language barrier?  Some of your posts are difficult to understand, which can lead to downvotes.  Based just on the number of votes on your account I doubt this is serial downvoting, but if it is the algorithm will catch it.

Comment: Anyway I did my best to show in this site is happening ugly things! I am tired. It is disappointing and disgusting at the same moment. bye for now!

Comment: @PersianCat Well I for one downvoted this post because: 1 - It's not a question but more of a rant, 2 - you have a victim complex that bothers me in light of the quality of your posts, 3 - it's very difficult to see what you are trying to say, 4 - you seem to have no awareness that your posts are low quality.  If someone downvotes you it doesn't mean that they are a mean person who dislikes you for no reason, it COULD mean that your post is not very good.  If this is a pattern you have seen elsewhere, perhaps the issue is NOT everyone else in the world, but the issue is the quality of posts.

Comment: -2 for what? OMG! Thanks people and mods! I have no more question as I got my answer. I think it is the most valid evidence which proves the validity of second answer of mine to my own question about the flight 655! The same reaction and logic. Amazing! :))

Comment: I think we've settled all that's going to be settled in this comment discussion. I've been involved to look at your complaint and I've posted a response. Please have a look :)

Comment: Your latest update leaves me little option but to close this discussion. Meta Politics is not your personal blog, and while we tolerated your rants about this site, using it as a platform to air your grievances with other sites is just too much.

Answer (score 9):

Now that we had time to examine the voting records, some of the downvotes against your posts were removed. Some remain, as there was nothing suspicious about them. The matter is now concluded.

"Patience is bitter, but its fruit is sweet." - Jean-Jacques Rousseau

---

There is an automated process that detects abusive voting patterns and reverses them (if there are any). The process runs once per day and creates a permanent record of any abusive voting patterns it detects. I'm asking you *again* to wait 24 hours before you conclude that you were the target of serial downvoting. When the script runs we will have confirmation of any abusive voting against your account, and if you were targeted rest assured that we will take all the proper actions that we need to take.

Serial downvoting or not, I strongly advise you to consider toning down your comments. I have deleted several of your comments that were little more than random accusations and borderline insults, and a fellow moderator deleted rude comments from you in the past. While I realize there is a language barrier, the behaviour you've exhibited in the short time you've been a member of our community is neither a result of poor English skills nor seems to be improving. Consider this your final warning, any more rude commentary will not be tolerated.

Regarding your update, if you think that I have abused my moderator powers or have any other issues with my moderation activities then feel free to [contact Stack Exchange directly](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/help/other).

Answer (score 6):

I'm Tim Post - a community manager for Stack Exchange. As this is a topic that is frequently raised, I'll give you some insight and advice on what to do when this happens.

> ***tl;dr;*** — *Wait for the system to revert the votes as you double check your posts. If that doesn't happen and you feel strongly that they were targeted, involve a moderator. If no action was subsequently taken, the votes weren't targeted. Skim the bold if you're short on time.*

While coincidence may strongly suggest to you that a single person has targeted your contributions with down votes, more often than not that's simply *not* the case. Votes are an indicator from your community that something might be incorrect, misleading, vague or biased in a post that you have written. The very first thing to do is examine the posts from a neutral perspective and see if something about them could be better.

On somewhat controversial sites, especially a site about *politics*, a single post shared via Twitter, chat, IRC, or any other means will attract a bit of attention, some of that attention is bound to be negative. A short succession of unexplained down votes more often than not actually comes from several people.

As [Yannis points out](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1303/94), we do have checks in place to detect and reverse votes fitting targeted patterns. This is a maintenance job that runs once each day on every site. If targeted voting is detected by the algorithm, the votes are invalidated and evidence of the activity is preserved in a report that moderators can see. Additionally, moderators are able to examine a high level overview of the same patterns, to the degree that they can sanity check the automated process.

If you feel that you've been targeted by a specific user, the first thing you should do is ***wait*** and ***do not retaliate, under any circumstances***. If those votes *were* cast by the same user, the system *will* reverse them. If a day has passed and the votes have not yet been invalidated, then it's probably because they didn't come from the same user.

If you *still* feel that something fishy is going on, like perhaps someone figuring out a way to evade the system then flag one of your posts (doesn't matter which one) for moderator attention, select 'other' as your reason and let them know:

> I've been suspiciously down-voted. I waited for the votes to reverse, and they have not. Please look into this.

The moderator will then examine all voting patterns surrounding your account and quite possibly involve us to look deeper if necessary. If no action has been taken after getting *this* far, then there's simply no action to take. While you are free to contact us directly for additional resolution using the contact link at the bottom of every site, be advised that we've *very likely* already been involved and found that the data simply doesn't support a targeted scenario.

Above all else, when participating in any online community, ***never take it personally*** - if you find yourself suspecting some kind of cabal is determined to silence you, then you probably need to take a well deserved break.

Comment: Of course, logically speaking, if a cabal was out to silence someone, they'd say EXACTLY the last paragraph you did... </tinfoil_on>

Answer (score 4):

It would be difficult to prove serial downvoting with such a small sample size. That being said, you only suffered 9 total downvotes, for a total of -18 points. This is hardly anything to worry about. You could make up this loss of points by:

-Asking a good of question, and getting 4 Upvotes.

-Providing a good answer, and getting 2 Upvotes.

-Deleting your poor quality answer for Iran Flight 655 (+10), and some variation of the above.

There is a small possibility that you were serially downvoted. You received 3 downvotes within a minute on three different questions. It might also be the case that your poor answer alerted someone that your other questions might be of poor quality, and they voted accordingly.

-[Last face to face meeting between USA and Iran](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1075/when-was-the-last-face-to-face-meeting-between-iran-government-and-usa-governmen)

-[Political Consequence of an appology](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1116/what-are-the-political-consequences-of-an-official-apology-for-a-governement)

-[USA ok to advertise peaceful political meetings](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1074/is-it-allowed-in-the-united-states-to-advertise-for-a-peaceful-political-meeting)

The first one isn't a bad question, per say, but the terms for what constitutes an "official" meeting isn't clearly defined.

The second one cannot have a real answer (other than, "it depends"). It asks for the answerers to predict the future and it isn't worded very clearly. (Although, that is probably just a language barrier issue).

The third one suffers from language issues. This question is actually quite interesting though. Someone could edit it into something more interesting, asking for historical examples of protests against the government, the Supreme Courts rulings about what is/isn't protected under the First Amendments "petition the Government for a redress grieviences."

Comment: @PersianCat, it wasn't me who downvoted you. Just pointing to some possible explanations, and putting the "serial downvoting" in perspective.

Comment: Just a note: Several people took the time to politely explain their downvotes on Persian Cat's posts (especially the Flight 655 answer), and some even went a step further and suggested improvements. However the discussion soon turned awry (I never understood why), and I was left with little option but to purge all the comments. I started deleting them selectively, but for every comment I deleted two new appeared, and... well... run out of patience I guess.

Comment: @YannisRizos - you would make [a VERY poor Hēraklēs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lernaean_Hydra)

Comment: @DVK Hm? I did exactly what my mythical forefather did. "The weakness of the Hydra was that it was invulnerable only if it retained at least one head." - When I realized it's the same with comments, I cut them all down at once with one swift motion of my mod hammer.

Comment: @YannisRizos - yes, but didn't he cut off heads for several hours/days first? I don't have the source handy for how long he waited for Iolaus.